# Google Maps Display in Android: +/- symbols visible, no map

Tags: android, google-maps

For some reason, I have my Google Maps application attempting to run, but it gives me a grey screen and only the +/- options for the map.

I've used two guides extensively, and I continue to have the same problem.
I've googled extensively, and it always seems that the issue must be my API console or my dependencies, and so I've included screenshots of those:
[image]
It must be noted that I am storing these files in a folder that syncs to Dropbox - I don't know if that's a bad thing or not.

When I export it as an android application, I'm using a keystore that I made, and an alias that I made. I am doing this because I am trying to run it on my phone as opposed to the emulator (because I've heard Play isn't working well with emulators). I'm extracting it like so:

[image]

And finally, here's my console:
[image]

Here's my Manifest:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
    android:name="com.hotspotprime.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.hotspotprime.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.hotspotprime.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyDQVfQ7cZRpTtMRqG3k_ih7Jt-vsgfjnCY" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Code:
    package com.hotspotprime;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: since your min sdk is 13 you can extend standard `Activity` instead of `FragmentActivity` and i guess your are using `MapFragment`.

Comment: I figured it out. So that someone else doesn't have to go through this hell, don't use an old keystore that has already been entered into the API console under a different package name. I just made a new keystore and it fixed the problem.